# Is it possible to use .each() arrays to position many divs?

Tags: jquery, html, each

Just a little disclaimer: I am a total newcomer to jquery/javascript programming, and know only the basics for html/css designing..

I have been trying to randomly position a  number of soundcloud widgets on a page. I seem to have managed to achieve this - but to do so i've had : to create a new div id in css, allocate each widget to a seperate div id name, and then write a function to move each div individualy.  I tried using .each(), but from what i can gather in other questions, this does not work to run through divs, only div.class names... from here on in i got very confused trying .each(); .parent(); class names etc etc in testing..

this is the js i have to copy each time (just changing the number after 'scTrack'):

```
(function() {

var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    $div = $('#scTrack1'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

$div.css({
    left: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
    top: Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax)
});
});
```

css:

```
#scTrack1 {
position:absolute;
height:70px;
width: 200px;
}
```

html

```
<div id="scTrack1">
<object height="81" width="100%"> <param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F67155680&amp;show_comments=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=000000"></param> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F67155680&amp;show_comments=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=000000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> </object>    
</div>
```

here is my example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antrgor_reiz/scVRS/

what i want to achieve is to have one div defined in css - which is used for all the different soundcloud widgets - and some js that will loop through each instance of that div and run the function to reposition the div..

is this possible??

thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.each()` to loop over any jQuery object, created from any selector (with or without class names).

```
$("div").each(function() { ... });       // loop through all divs
$("div.test").each(function() { ... } ); // loop through all divs of class "test"
$(".test").each(function() { ... });     // loop through any elements of class "test"
```

For your case, this would do the trick:

```
$(function() {    
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width();

    // process each div that is a child of "container"
    $("#container div").each(function() {

        // get the current div's dimensions
        var $div = $(this),
            divWidth = $div.width(),
            divHeight = $div.height(),
            heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
            widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

        // set the current div's position
        $div.css({
            left: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
            top: Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax)
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/scVRS/62/

Comment: P.S. I don't normally like to create variables that are only used once. Here is a shorter version of the above that doesn't bother creating `divWidth, divHeight, heightMax or widthMax`: http://jsfiddle.net/scVRS/65/ (I left them in in my answer above so that you could see how similar my solution was to your original code).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `four` differnt function of same functionality you can use `.each()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('object').each(function(){
        var $pDiv = $(this).parent('div');
        var docHeight = $(document).height(),
                docWidth = $(document).width(),
                $div = $pDiv,
                divWidth = $div.width(),
                divHeight = $div.height(),
                heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
                widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

         $div.css({
             left: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
             top: Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax)
         });        

    })
});
```

​
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/scVRS/59/